# How to execute pipeline on self-hosted build agent as non-root user

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have built self-hosted ubuntu agents running in docker.

All works fine, build agent is working etc.

except everything in pipeline steps is being executed as root instead of non-root user.

E.g. When I try to execute "npm ci" and I look at my build-agent logs:

`; node bin location = /usr/bin/node
; cwd = /azp/agent/_work/1/s/Core
; HOME = /root`

vs logs from Microsoft hosted build-agent:

`; node bin location = /usr/local/bin/node
; cwd = /home/vsts/work/1/s/Core
; HOME = /home/vsts`

this gives me issues in lot of stages as running some commands as root requires different settings etc.
Does anyone know how to change it from ROOT?

I tried within **dockerfile** and within **start.sh** script provided by microsoft but that did not worked. Build agent would not start at all if I would execute start.sh as docker user instead of root.
Any clues? ideas?

Comment: did you try out below answer, any update?

Answer (score 1):

You can install your linux agent under the account to change it from root like `/home/{accountname}/`.

Below is the steps about how to install the linux agent under the non-root user.

Connect to linux agent by non-root user

```
ssh useraccount@linuxIp
```

Create a folder and cd the folder.

```
mkdir myagent && cd myagent
```

Download the package from the url.

```
wget https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.155.1/vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.155.1.tar.gz
```

Unzip the file.

```
tar xzf vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.155.1.gz
```

Config the linux Agent

Comment: so this would potentially work if I would like to create it manually. What Im trying to do is to create automated build and deployment of build agent on a Docker within Azure DevOps, trying to follow this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops